# fs.writeFile(sqlRequest, JSON.stringify(obj)) not outputting SQLite data to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to output code from an SQLite3 database with Javascript and Node.js, it selects the correct data and outputs each row to the console but doesn't add it to a JSON file using the code below:

```
var obj;  
db.serialize(function(){
    req = sqlRequest;
    console.log(req); //sql request to console
    db.each(req, function(err, row){
        console.log(row); //outputs every entry correctly
        obj += row;
    });

    db.close();
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
fs.writeFile(sqlRequest, JSON.stringify(obj), function(err){
    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Json saved to: " + sqlRequest);
    }

    console.log("The file is saved");
});
```

All it's outputting to the JSON file with this code is 'undefined'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: put last half of your code just before `db.close()`. You are trying to save object before it is populated

Comment: It's still outputting undefined to console and to the JSON file when I change the code